# How to enable proxy in react-slingshot (by coryhouse) so I can call my Django REST APIs?

Tags: reactjs, browser-sync, react-slingshot

I have a Django development server running on port 8050 with several REST APIs that I would like to serve to my React app, which is composed by [react-slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) and is running on localhost:3002.

What I want is for my Javascript code, such as `fetch('api/v1/employees')`, to actually call localhost:8050 instead of localhost:3002.

I see [raythree in a github discussion](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/pull/93#issuecomment-238322952) was able to find a solution to my question, however, I am unable to get his solution to work. I implemented his advice exactly as he has it, but the code acts as if I made no changes at all.

Here is what my code in tools/srcServer.js looks like right now:

```
// This file configures the development web server
// which supports hot reloading and synchronized testing.

// Require Browsersync along with webpack and middleware for it
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
// Required for react-router browserHistory
// see https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/204#issuecomment-102623643
import historyApiFallback from 'connect-history-api-fallback';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';

const bundler = webpack(config);

const serverProxy = proxy('/api', {
  target: "http://0.0.0.0:8050",
  changeOrigin: true, // set true for hosted sites
  logLevel: 'debug'
});

// Run Browsersync and use middleware for Hot Module Replacement
browserSync({
  port: 3000,
  ui: {
    port: 3001
  },

  server: {
    baseDir: 'src',

    middleware: [
      historyApiFallback(),

      webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
        // Dev middleware can't access config, so we provide publicPath
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath,

        // These settings suppress noisy webpack output so only errors are displayed to the console.
        noInfo: true,
        quiet: false,
        stats: {
          assets: false,
          colors: true,
          version: false,
          hash: false,
          timings: false,
          chunks: false,
          chunkModules: false
        }

        // for other settings see
        // https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-middleware
      }),

      // bundler should be the same as above
      webpackHotMiddleware(bundler),

      serverProxy,
    ]
  },

  // no need to watch '*.js' here, webpack will take care of it for us,
  // including full page reloads if HMR won't work
  files: [
    'src/*.html'
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Apparently `serverProxy` needs to be indexed **before** `webpackDevMiddleware` and `webpackHotMiddleware` in the `middleware` array!

```
// This file configures the development web server
// which supports hot reloading and synchronized testing.

// Require Browsersync along with webpack and middleware for it
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
// Required for react-router browserHistory
// see https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/204#issuecomment-102623643
import historyApiFallback from 'connect-history-api-fallback';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';

const bundler = webpack(config);

const serverProxy = proxy('/api', {
  target: "http://0.0.0.0:8050",
  changeOrigin: true, // set true for hosted sites
  logLevel: 'debug'
});

// Run Browsersync and use middleware for Hot Module Replacement
browserSync({
  port: 3000,
  ui: {
    port: 3001
  },

  server: {
    baseDir: 'src',

    middleware: [
      historyApiFallback(),

      // The order of serverProxy is important. It will not work if it is indexed
      // after the webpackDevMiddleware in this array.
      serverProxy,

      webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
        // Dev middleware can't access config, so we provide publicPath
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath,

        // These settings suppress noisy webpack output so only errors are displayed to the console.
        noInfo: true,
        quiet: false,
        stats: {
          assets: false,
          colors: true,
          version: false,
          hash: false,
          timings: false,
          chunks: false,
          chunkModules: false
        }

        // for other settings see
        // https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-middleware
      }),

      // bundler should be the same as above
      webpackHotMiddleware(bundler),
    ]
  },

  // no need to watch '*.js' here, webpack will take care of it for us,
  // including full page reloads if HMR won't work
  files: [
    'src/*.html'
  ]
});
```